# Computation of the mean of a random variable to estimate algorithm complexity

Tags: probability, computational-complexity

I made an incremental algorithm which I would like to evaluate the complexity. The algorithm works with a sliding window of size n.

To study the complexity, the window is considered full and the data present are ${x_{1},...,x_{n}}$ . They are assumed to be random, i.i.d, but with no assumption regarding their distribution. In particular, they are not necessarily bounded. Finally, the most recent data is $x_{n+1}$.

The complexity of the algorithm depends on the distance from $x_{n+1}$ to its “nearest lower value” $x_{l}$ whose index is $l=\max\left\{ k\in\{1...n\}\;st\;x_{k}<x_{n+1}\right\}$. The distance $d$ is then $d=n+1-l$.

$d$ is obviously a random variable, and I would like to determine its mean, which would give the algorithm complexity.

I first thought $d$ was a geometric variable with argument 1/2 since $P\left(x_{n+1}\geq x_{n}\right)=1/2$ (which I cannot prove either), so $E\left[d\right]=2$ but it is not the case. Indeed, $x_{n+1}$ and $x_{n}$ are not independent so $d$ does not follow a geometric law. Moreover, I did some experiments on Excel to compute $E\left[d\right]$ using different distributions and it seems it does not depend on the distribution of the $x_{i}$ but on $n$ (I can not post the image, it confirms this result).

Below is a track I have tried to follow to determine $E\left[d\right]$ which proved unsuccessful:

$E\left[d\right]=\sum_{k=1...n}kP\left(d=k\right)$

and

$\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(d=k\right) & = & P\left(x_{n-k}<x_{n+1}\cap x_{n-k+1}\geq x_{n+1}\cap...\cap x_{n}\geq x_{n+1}\right)\\
 & = & \forall\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}\in\mathbb{R}\int_{\lambda_{1}<\lambda_{2}}P\left(x_{n-k}<\lambda_{1}\cap x_{n+1}\in\left[\lambda_{1};\lambda_{2}\right]\cap\bigcup_{j=n-k+1...n}x_{j}\geq\lambda_{2}\right)d\lambda_{1}d\lambda_{2}\\
 & = & \int_{\lambda_{1}<\lambda_{2}}P\left(x_{n-k}<\lambda_{1}\right)P\left(x_{n+1}\in\left[\lambda_{1};\lambda_{2}\right]\right)\sum_{j=n-k+1...n}P\left(x_{j}\geq\lambda_{2}\right)d\lambda_{1}d\lambda_{2}\\
 & = & \int_{\lambda_{1}<\lambda_{2}}F_{X}\left(\lambda_{1}\right)\left(F_{X}\left(\lambda_{2}\right)-F_{X}\left(\lambda_{1}\right)\right)\sum_{j=n-k+1...n}\left(1-F_{X}\left(\lambda_{2}\right)\right)d\lambda_{1}d\lambda_{2}
\end{eqnarray*}$

But I can not go any further ? Do you have any idea ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is this the same question? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139706/computation-of-the-mean-of-a-random-variable-to-estimate-algorithm-complexity

Comment: Yes it is. For those interested though, the answers are mostly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just gave an answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139706/computation-of-the-mean-of-a-random-variable-to-estimate-algorithm-complexity, that almost agrees with that of Wild Chan. I repost it here for comparison.

....

It seems to me that $P(d>k)=\tfrac1{k+1}$ for $k\in[0,n]$, so that $$E[d]=\sum_{k\ge 0}P(d>k)=H_{n+1}\simeq \ln n.$$ The reason is that the last $k+1$ terms of the sequence are in random order, so that the last one is the smallest among the last $k+1$ terms of the sequence with probability $P(d>k)=\tfrac1{k+1}$. When the last is the smallest of all I assume that $d$ is set equal to $n+1$. Does it make sense ?

For this to be valid, you need to assume that the probability distribution has no atoms, which is true for instance if it has a density of probability.

.....

Note that I obtain implicitly, for $n\ge k\ge 1$,
$$P(d=k)=\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$
and 
$$P(d=n+1)=\frac{1}{n+1},$$
to be compared with the solution by Wild Chan,
$$P(d=k)=\frac{1}{k^2+3k+2}=\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$
for $n-1\ge k\ge 0$, that is not a probability distribution, for it does not add to one. There is also a shift due to different understandings of the definition of $d$, mine being that the minimum value of $d$ is 1, while the other solution assumes that $P(d=0)=1/2$, it seems. This explains the difference $-2+\tfrac1{n+1}$ between the 2 solutions.

Also note a shorter computation below:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F'(y)F(y)(1-F(y))^kdy
&=&
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F'(y)(1-F(y))^kdy -
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F'(y)(1-F(y))^{k+1}dy \\
&=&
\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{k+2},
\end{eqnarray*}$$
that agrees with Wild Chan result too.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Actually, this is the right result as I checked on my experiments. The shift you use is the good one. But I do not understand clearly the reason you give ! Actually, using your explaination, I would say that p(d=k)=1/k+1, since if the last one among k+1 is the smallest with probability 1/K+1, then the one before the last one would be the smallest with the same probability and so on...Obviously I missed a point in your answer, could you give me more details ? Moreover, I do not understand your mean formula. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @GillesM the formula for the mean is a classic avatar of the integration by parts, and should be found easily in Wikipedia or textbooks. I would say that $d\le k$ is equivalent to "the nearest lower value is in the subsequence $x_{n-k+1}, x_{n-k+2}, \dots , x_{n}$" or again equivalent to "$x_{n+1}$  is not the smaller in the subsequence $x_{n-k+1}, x_{n-k+2}, \dots , x_{n}, x_{n+1}$".

Comment: Ok, thanks. I still do not understand the formula$E[d]=\sum_{k\geq0}P\left(d>k\right)$
since I only know the classical $E[d]=\sum_{k\geq0}kP\left(d=k\right)$
and cannot figure out how are they equivalent. I also do not get the
$\int F^{\prime}\left(y\right)F\left(y\right)\left(1-F\left(y\right)\right)^{k}dy=\int F^{\prime}\left(y\right)\left(1-F\left(y\right)\right)^{k}dy-\int F^{\prime}\left(y\right)\left(1-F\left(y\right)\right)^{k+1}dy$.
Do you know a simple book or website where I could find these answers
?

Comment: Ok, I continued working on it, and I've got the $\int F^{\prime}\left(y\right)F\left(y\right)\left(1-F\left(y\right)\right)^{k}dy=\int F^{\prime}\left(y\right)\left(1-F\left(y\right)\right)^{k}dy-\int F^{\prime}\left(y\right)\left(1-F\left(y\right)\right)^{k+1}dy$. However, I still do not understand the $E[d]=\sum_{k\geq0}P\left(d>k\right)$.

Comment: Try http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esp%C3%A9rance_math%C3%A9matique#Cas_d.27une_variable_al.C3.A9atoire_positive

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think $P(d=k)$ should be calculated by joint distribution.
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(d=k) &=& P(x_{n-k}<y\ \cap x_{n-k+1}\geq y\ \cap\ldots\cap x_n\geq y) \\
&=& \int_{x_{n-k}<y,\ x_{n-k+1}\geq y,\ldots,x_n\geq y}\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y)dx_1\ldots dx_ndy \\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(y)dy \left(\int_{-\infty}^y\varphi(x_{n-k})dx_{n-k}\int_y^\infty\varphi(x_{n-k+1})dx_{n-k+1}\ \ldots\ \int_y^\infty\varphi(x_n)dx_n\right) \\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty F'(y)F(y)(1-F(y))^kdy \\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty F'\left(\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^iC_k^iF^{i+1}\right)dy \\
&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{(-1)^iC_k^i}{i+2}F^{i+2}\right)'dy \\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{(-1)^iC_k^i}{i+2}=\frac{1}{k^2+3k+2}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

May be clumsy... And then the expectation is obtained
$$Ed=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k}{k^2+3k+2}=H_{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}-2$$
So the asypmtotic complexity of $d$ is $\Theta(\ln n)$.

---

In addition, if we use the property of symmetry, and calculate
$$P(x_{n-k}>y\ \cap x_{n-k+1}\leq y\ \cap\ldots\cap x_n\leq y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F'(y)(1-F(y))F(y)^kdy$$
we can get the answer far more faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can I just ask for 2 clairifications : 1. What is the H function ? 2. How do you go from line 4 to line 5 ?

Comment: @GillesM $H_n$ represents the partial summation of harmonic series. And line 4 transforms into line 5 by binomial formula.

Comment: Thanks ! I eventually found it on this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Sorry, I still have questions...1. From line 5 to 6, why i+2 appears in denominator ? 2. From line 6 to 7, where the F^i+2 is gone ?

Comment: @GillesM Notice that in line 6, there's a apostrophe outside the parenthesis. And $F$ is gone because $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(y) dy=F(\infty)-F(-\infty)=1$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still miss one step. I understand that $\int F^{\prime}=1$, but what about $\int\left(F^{2}\right)^{\prime}$, $\int\left(F^{3}\right)^{\prime}$,...which are part of the sum ?

Comment: @GillesM No difference. Because $F(-\infty)=0$ and $F(\infty)=1$. I omit the limit sign here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said to Chassaing in the comments, I do not want to bother you indefinitely with what must be very easy points. Nevertheless, I still do not understand why $\int\left(F^{2}\right)^{\prime}$, $\int\left(F^{3}\right)^{\prime}$ equal 1. I do not see either how do you use the Harmonic formula $H_{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}C_{i}^{k}}{i}$ with $\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{i}C_{i}^{k}}{i+2}$ ? Do you know a very simple book or website where I could find these answers ?