# Power of cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470335/computation-of-the-mean-of-a-random-variable-to-estimate-algorithm-complexity) about a month ago on Math Stackexchange and received two great answers.

Based on these, I wrote that (which is simply a mix between WildChan's and Chassaing's answers):
\begin{array}{rcl}
P\left(d=k\right) & = & P\left(x_{n}<x_{n-1}\cap...\cap x_{n}<x_{n-k+1}\cap x_{n}\geq x_{n-k}\right)\\
 & = & \int_{x_{n}<x_{n-1},...,x_{n}<x_{n-k+1},x_{n}\geq x_{n-k}}f_{X}\left(x_{n-k},x_{n-k+1},...,x_{n}\right)dx_{n-k}...dx_{n}\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_{X}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}\right)F_{X}\left(x_{n}\right)\left(1-F_{X}\left(x_{n}\right)\right)^{k-1}dx_{n}\\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_{X}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}\right)\left(1-F_{X}\left(x_{n}\right)\right)^{k-1}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_{X}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}\right)\left(1-F_{X}\left(x_{n}\right)\right)^{k}dx_{n}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(F_{X}^{k}\left(x_{n}\right)\right)^{\prime}dx_{n}-\frac{1}{k+1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(F_{X}^{k+1}\left(x_{n}\right)\right)^{\prime}dx_{n}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\\
\end{array}

Nonetheless, I still do not understand how the last line can be deduced, i.e. why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(F_{X}^{k}\left(x_{n}\right)\right)^{\prime}dx_{n}=1$ ? I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(F_{X}\left(x_{n}\right)\right)^{\prime}dx_{n}=1$, but I do not see why the integral of $\left(F^{k}\right)^{^\prime}$ would be 1 as well.

Can someone explain me ? Thanks !

Comment: aren't you stating that $(F_X^k(x_n))'$ is the derivative of $(F_X^k(x_n))$?  So you are integrating the derivative of the CDF over the entire real line, if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Yes, but I'm intergrating the derivative of the CDF power k over the entire line...It should make a difference, should'nt it  ?

Comment: No difference, all that counts is that $(F_X(\infty))^k-(F_X(-\infty))^k=1^k-0^k=1$.

Comment: Sure ! Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the question...